# Cannot register class in Ebean server (Play Framework 2 - Java)

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

I am getting the following error when running my Play Framework 2.2.x (Java) project:

```
Configuration error
Cannot register class [models.SomeClass] in Ebean server
```

The error messages displayed in the browser points me to the line `ebean.default="models.*"` in my `application.conf`, and the console tells me that I have a `java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack` in one of my methods. There is nothing special about the methods for which this happens, and it has happened for a handfull of methods now.

I have found out that the error can be avoided by using a static method instead: that is by replacing `someObject.doJob()`by `SomeClass.doJob(someObject)`. I have used this hack, and it works, but I am not very happy about making all my methods static when they should not be.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a way to fix it (without making the methods static)?

Comment: Please provide full stackterace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED: It turned out that the methods with problems all referenced fields that were marked as final. Apparently, Play Framework / Ebean does not like final fields in Entity classes. After removing the `final` keyword from these field, the problem went away.

Comment: How did you figure out which fields have the problem? I don't use `final` but am still getting this error.

Comment: I knew which methods had the problem and just looked at which fields were used in those. Unfortunately Play doesn't tell you anything about which fields are the problem. If none of your fields are final, then I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

I am using play 2.3 and faced the same problem.

I created an abstract class and another one extending this abstract class. This cause an error. Looks like ebean consider every class extending an abstract class as a final class and throw the same error message.

Moving all the classes in another package removed the problem.