# Cannot register class [models.Invoice] in Ebean server

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I have two models:

```
1. Customer (Id, Name, address, etc)
2. Invoice (Id, Customer, Date)
```

When I try to run this I get:

`Cannot register class [models.Invoice] in Ebean server`.

And the error points to **application.conf** file's line with

**ebean.default="models.*"**

The output is

[image]

**Is the data type for these models cannot be a model it self?**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361370/cannot-register-class-in-ebean-server-play-framework-2-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647877/play-framework-2-3-x-server-error-cannot-register-class) doesn't help me.

Tell me if the presented things aren't enough.

Thank you!

Comment: Restart the play app, it might solve the issue. I used to do the same, whenever i getting this kind of error and it works for me.

Comment: @Sivakumar Did it but no luck

Comment: @Nabin could you show us the code of the Invoice class?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have final constants in your class and therefore Ebean doesnt like it as pointed out here: [Cannot register class in Ebean server (Play Framework 2 - Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361370/cannot-register-class-in-ebean-server-play-framework-2-java)

Comment: I have mentioned, that the final constants are not present. See the links given.